# Copy file from docker container to local host

Tags: docker

I have a docker container

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
44758917bf50        jupyter/pyspark-notebook   "tini -g -- start-no\u2026"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp   thirsty_lamport
```

Inside I am running `jupyter notebook`. I have an `ipynb` that I would like to copy. Inside of the `notebook`, I see what the current directory is by typing `pwd`

```
[in 42] pwd
[out 42]'/home/jovyan'
```

If I now say from the host machine:

```
idf@ubvm:~/Documents$ docker cp 44758917bf50:/root/jovyan/pysparkex.ipynb ./pyex.ipypnb
```

I get an error:

```
Error: No such container:path: 44758917bf50:/root/jovyan/pysparkex.ipynb
```

I get an error no matter what path I choose, so for example same error if I remove 'root' from the path above.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

This got me much further:

```
idf@ubvm:~/Documents$ docker exec 44758917bf50 ls /home/jovyan
pysparkex.ipynb
Untitled.ipynb
work
```

Now I have to figure out what the `docker cp` command is.

Comment: The pwd showed `/home/jovyan` but you tried to copy from `/root/jovyan`

Comment: If the error persists, include the output of `docker exec 44758917bf50 ls /home/jovyan`

Comment: That helped quite a bit. See EDIT in original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you confused the source dir in container and target dir in local machine, try *docker cp 44758917bf50:/home/jovyan/pysparkex.ipynb ./pyex.ipypnb*